# How to show values only from specific java classes?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have a table which contains all sorts of attributes set in constructors of java classes. I need to show all attributes but when I want to do it the easy way i get nullpointers. I have already tried jstl if and jstl choose to do the trick.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty animal.getEarSize()}">
        not set!
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ${animal.getEarSize()}
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

But when I try to run it I get HTTP status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page.
animal is the variable in an jstl for loop and not all animals have an earsize in the constructor.

What am i doing wrong here?
Is there another way to do this or is this the only way to do this with jstl choose or if?

Edit: I'm using a method in a controller which gives a map with animal objects where i'm looping through.

```
public AfricanElephant(String color, String bodyCovering, String name, double weight, Gender gender, int earSize) {
    super(color, bodyCovering, name, weight, gender, maxNumberOfEggs, earSize);
}

public Parrot(String color, String bodyCovering, String name, double weight, Gender gender) {
    super(color, bodyCovering, name, weight, gender, maxNumberOfEggs);
}
```

These are two sample constructors in elephant constructor there is a variable for earsize but in parrot constructor there is no variable for earsize.

Edit: i have changed the choose to this:

```
<td> 
            <c:if test="${animal.getClass().name eq 'myPackage.MyPath.AfricanElephant'}">${animal.earSize}</c:if>
```

This fixes the HTTP status 500 error but now it displays 0 in the table instead of the earsize set by me.

my controller:

```
@Controller("animalController")
```

public class AnimalController {

```
 ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

@RequestMapping(value = "/animaloverview", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String animals(Map<String, Object> model, @RequestParam(value = "race", required = false, defaultValue = "") String race){
    if(race.isEmpty()){
         model.put("animals", Zoo.getInstance().getAllAnimals());

    }

    else{
        model.put("animals", Zoo.getInstance().getAnimalsByRace(race));
   }

    return "animalkingdom";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check it that way. EL `empty` only works for empty string or null, not for non-existent property. You could either add a `getEarSize()` method to the Parrot which returns a `null`, or check if the animal is `instanceof` AfricanElephant and then print the `${animal.earSize}` (not getEarSize()!).

Something like:

```
<c:if test="${animal.getClass().name eq 'package.path.AfricanElephant'}">
```

Also, Amit Goel's answer is wrong. **EL is using the getter method, and not accessing the property directly (and they should be private).** If you have a method e.g.: `getFullSize()` which returns a calculation's result, but you don't have fullSize property, you can still say `${animal.fullSize}` and it will display the result.

Comment: i have fixed the HTTP status error by using this:








`code`<td> <c:catch var="exception">${animal.earSize}</c:catch> 
                <c:if test="exception==null">
                    ${animal.getEarSize()}
                </c:if>
            </td>`code`

Comment: I understand that it solved the problem but it's not the way you want to treat it (if you want to learn of course).

Comment: Plus you are still using getEarSize() which will not work.

Comment: i have changed it to what you said but the result is still that it displays 0 instead of the amount i set it to.

Comment: I'd need to see more code to help. If you can share the project zipped I'll have a look at it, there might be problems with the controller as well.

Comment: i cant send the project for copyright reasons but i can send you the controller i'll post it in my question

Comment: Ah, I see now, that's Spring framework. I haven't used it before, so I can't help you with that part. I can only suggest that you should add some breakpoints to key lines, and determine when your values get lost, or if they are ever set.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use java getter `getEarSize()`. If your entity has the property earSize just check

`<c:when test="${empty animal.earSize}">`

Comment: done that but no change to the HTTP status 500. still not working.